# Is it ok to repurpose SKPayment.applicationUsername?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, storekit

Regarding `SKPayment.applicationUsername`, it says [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/storekit/skpayment/1506116-applicationusername)...

> This is used to help the store detect irregular activity. For example,
>   in a game, it would be unusual for dozens of different iTunes Store
>   accounts making purchases on behalf of the same in-game character.
>
> The recommended implementation is to use a one-way hash of the user’s
>   account name to calculate the value for this property.

This property is optional. So, am I allowed to use it for something else entirely? I want to use it to store details about the product that are not stored in iTunes.

Comment: Did you use it?

Comment: No, I didn't think it was worth the risk.

Answer (score 2):

`SKPayment.applicationUsername` is only used by Apple on the backend for fraud detection. They can use it to see if a single user is processing purchases on multiple devices, or processing purchases more rapidly than normal.

This value is unreadable except for on the payment you set it on, you aren't able to read `SKPaymentTransaction.payment.applicationUsername` it is always `nil`.

On a side note, I think this is a flaw in `StoreKit` as it makes it impossible to link transactions within an iTunes account to an application account, so if you have users sharing an iTunes account it is very difficult to not double grant purchased content.

Comment: Exactly. Is it by design?

Comment: Unfortunately yes. The API provides little or no benefit to the developer and worse is actually misleading.

Comment: Is there an alternative to the API?

Comment: Depends on the kind of information you want to store. Most commonly I want to store the username of the purchaser so it can only be used by one user. If you want to store something complex associated with the purchase you probably need your own datastore that maps `transaction_id` to the information you care about. If you just want just want to assign a transaction to a user id you might need a backend or [some hosted equivalent](https://www.revenuecat.com).

Comment: But you don't have a transaction id until after contacting Apple. If in the meantime the app restarts, you have to guess what the user was trying to purchase.

Comment: Yes correct. You can set stuff on `applicationUsername` of the `SKPayment` object that you create, however, it won't be there on the `SKPaymentTransaction.payment` once it is returned.

Comment: I think that validation should be achieved by Receipt validation. Although Receipt validation is a massive drag for a small application (since it includes decryption and implementation of OpenSSL) there are ways to validate Receipt locally on the device since it's unique per device per application. Receipts can also be validated against Apple's server but not directly from the user's device but instead by uploading the encrypted Receipt to your backend server and then to Apple server. This is the only true way to validate purchases and avoid multiple grants to a single user.

Comment: The Receipt contains all the info you would need to validate the user making the purchase, it's stored locally on the device and is encrypted. So there is no need to store the purchasing user info separately. The only challenge is to "unpack" that receipt and read it's payload, but once you overcome it it shouldn't be problem. There are many other issues to think about when using receipts though. Separate discussion.